# How can I remove the Ubuntu One icon from my panel bar?

Tags: icons, panel

I am new to Ubuntu, and am using Ubuntu 13.10 64-bit. The Ubuntu One icon is between WiFi and keyboard icons.

Here is a screenshot.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

**If you want to disable this indicator** from being showing automatically, disable Ubuntu One from startup applications. You will not see it there by default. Run the following command in a terminal. (copy-paste from here)

```
sudo sed 's/NoDisplay=true/NoDisplay=false/g' -i /etc/xdg/autostart/*.desktop
```

Then open startup applications (click on Dash=Ubuntu icon up left and write: startup) and deselect the Ubuntu One from being startingsud up automatically.

[image]

**If you want to completely remove the application.**

Remove "**Ubuntu One**" and "**Ubuntu One Music Store**" using the Software Center.

Or type in the terminal (Ctrl + Alt + T)

```
sudo apt-get remove ubuntuone-* rhythmbox-ubuntuone
```

I am not sure if removing only the rhythmbox plugin does the job.

Comment: Hey, I followed your steps, and deselected "Ubuntu One". However, it is still not going away from my panel. Do I need to reboot my computer as well?